# Multiple if blocks or single if/else block?

Tags: performance, logic

Which will typically have better running time, multiple `if` blocks or a single `if/else` block?

```
if (statement1) {
    /* do something */
    return result;
}
if (statement2) {
    /* do something */
    return result;
}
if (statement3) {
    /* do something */
    return result;
}
```

Versus:

```
if (statement1) {
    /* do something */
    return result;
} else if (statement2) {
    /* do something */
    return result;
} else if (statement3) {
    /* do something */
    return result;
}
```

I've always used the first style when the logical statements weren't in any way related, and the second if they were.

**EDIT**

To clarify why this thought popped into my head, I am programming a prime checker and have an `if` block that looks something like this:

```
if(n<2) return 0;
if(n==2) return 1;
if(n%2==0) return 0;
...
```

Comment: I'd say using the correct logic outweights the performance. Take into account a chain of ifs would need additional statements to achieve the same logic as a if-elif chain.

Comment: it's completely different logic. scenario 1, all 3 things could happen. scenario 2, only 1 thing could ever happen.

Comment: that said, 2 will perform better because the `else`s will only get executed if the condition is false. this concept is called short-circuiting.

Comment: I agree... two different logics out there. In the first code, all statements are checked, while in the second set of code, if any one of the statements is true, it will ignore the rest.

Comment: `I've always used the first style when the logical statements weren't in any way related, and the second if they were.`

bingo.

Comment: What language?  Performance will be heavily dependent on compile-time optimizations.

Comment: @MooseBoys I deliberately left off which language I am currently working in so that I could get a general idea of what to expect, but I am building a prime checker in C at the moment. `if(n<2) return 0; if(n==2) return 1; if(n%2==0) return 0;` That sort of thing.

Comment: Your general idea will be inaccurate in many cases though.  For example, for the code you just added, a C compiler will likely optimize it to a single comparison instruction.  For other cases where the conditions can be similarly flattened but the blocks themselves are complex, the compiler will likely emit a single jump instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which will typically have better running time, multiple if blocks or a single if/else block?

This is largely irrelevant as the semantics are different.

Now, if the goal is comparing the case of

```
if (a) { .. }
else if (b) { .. }
else { .. }
```

with

```
if (a) { return }
if (b) { return }
return
```

where no statements follow the conditional then they are the same and the compiler (in the case of a language like C) can optimize them equivalently.

Answer (score 0):

Always go for if else if... **when you know only one of the condition is to be executed**, Writing multiple if's will make the compiler to check for each and every condition even when the first condition is met which will have a performance overhead, multiple if's can be used when u want to check and perform multiple operations based on certain condition

Comment: it depends on the logic, as I said in my comment.

Comment: @pennstatephil I have mentioned above to go for if else if only when one condition is to be executed

Answer (score 0):

The if/else approach is faster, because it will skip evaluating the following conditions after one test succeeds.

However, the two forms are only equivalent if the conditions are mutually exclusive. If you just mindlessly convert one form into the other, you will introduce bugs. Make sure that you get the logic right.